# Creating a GET request with matrix parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

The webservice I'll be using expects matrix parameters:

```
http://tester.com/v1/customers;lastname=Jackson;firstname=Tim;bookingreference=7Y9UIY
```

instead of the usual

```
http://tester.com/v1/customers?lastname=Jackson&firstname=Tim&bookingreference=7Y9UIY
```

Is there anyway I can create a request using the Spring UriComponentsBuilder or an alternative?

I'm aware that I could just create it manually but hoped there was something more streamlined available.

Answer (score 2):

[UriBuilder](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) and [WebTarget](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html) of JAX-RS allow to add matrix params.

```
 UriBuilder builder = ...
 builder.matrixParam("lastname", "Jackson").matrixParam("firstname", "Tim")...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the  given().urlEncodingEnabled(false) This resolved my problem . After giving that the matrix parameter issue got resolved and able to hit the service properly