# Can't GET with matrix parameter using Rest-assured

Tags: json, rest, rest-assured

I have a request that looks like this :

http://localhost:8080/car/bmw;color=red

that returns the model of car and it's color as json data.
If I do the request without specifying color it will default to color green.

And the Java code:

```
String resourcePath = "http://localhost:8080/"
String carModel= "bmw"
String color = "red"

 RestAssuredResponseImpl response =
 (RestAssuredResponseImpl) given().
     when().get(resourcePath + "car/" + carModel + ";color=" + color );
```

When I copy/paste the url into browser it returns the json as expected , but when I try to get it with rest-assured I get a 404 not found error.
I've tried sending the request with param("color",color) but it just ignores the parameters and returns the default json.

Comment: Shouldn't the semicolon (;) in the URL be a question mark (?) to indicate the start of the request parameters?

Comment: Nope , this are matrix parameters.

Comment: Also I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744172/creating-a-get-request-with-matrix-parameters , but I can't figure out how to build a request like this .

Comment: Also https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/issues/417 , rest-assured currently does not support matrix parameters.

Comment: So you answered your own question :)

Comment: Question is answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387879/perform-get-request-with-matrix-parameters/35520745#35520745

Answer (score 1):

It seems that matrix-parameters are not supported yet. Today (January, 2020) this is still an open feature request for RestAssured: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/417

The recommended workaround is to switch-off URL-encoding.

```
given().urlEncodingEnabled(false)
    .when()
    .get("http://localhost:8080/car/bmw;color=red");
```