# Perform Get request with matrix parameters?

Tags: java, rest, parameters, get

I want to perform a GET request using matrix parameters. 
 http://localhost:8080/car/bmw;color=red

There is allready this question answered [Creating a GET request with matrix parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744172/creating-a-get-request-with-matrix-parameters)
,but there is not real step by step explanation there.

Comment: So what specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I can't find any understandable information on how to actually build the request and then receive the JSON data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can do it easier still using rest-assured.

given().urlEncodingEnabled(false).when(). get("http://localhost:8080/car/bmw;color=red")

Answer (score 0):

```
  ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
            ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/car/bmw;color=red");
            Response response = target.request().get();
            String value = response.readEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println(value);
            response.close();
```